# How do I increment (or not) a row based on criteria in another row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of PO Nos. in column D. Based on the PO Nos. I want to start counting distinct PO nos. only, and starting from 1. My data has repeating PO Nos. which are consecutive if more than one Item has been ordered in a single PO.  The desired output is in column E. [image]

I tried the following formula:

[image]

I was expecting the output which I have stated above in the table in Column E.

But the result is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Increment on Each Group's First Item

- Your posted formula produces the expected result.
- To get the desired result you could subtract the number of blank rows in column `E` from the formula's result:

  ```
  =IF(D2=D1,"",COUNTA(D$1:D1)-COUNTBLANK(E$1:E1))
  ```

  Put the 'subtracting' expressions in columns next to each other to better understand how it works.
- An improvement would be the following:

  ```
  =IF(D2=D1,"",MAX(E$1:E1)+1)
  ```